# See undeclared variables and unused imports in VS2017 (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

This is about Visual Studio Community.

I remember this was done in VS2015, yet this doesn't seem to be turned by default on in VS2017 and I can't find a way to do so.. is this feature not available in Community editions anymore?